# Clearing FBO doesn't clear everything

Tags: opengl, framebuffer

I have code which is the equivalent of the following:

init code:

```
glCullFace(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
//clear to pink
glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

GLuint textureObject;
glGenTextures(1, &textureObject);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureObject);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, 0);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 0);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 512, 512, 0, GL_RGBA,
    GL_UNSIGNED_BTYE, NULL);

GLuint fbo;
glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D,
    textureObject, 0);
glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
glDrawBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
assert(glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER)
    == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE);

Object obj = CreateAFullscreenQuad(textureObject);
```

draw code:

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
glViewport(0, 0, 512, 512);
//clear to cyan
GLfloat clear[] = {0, 1, 1, 1};
glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, clear);
SetUpPerspectiveAndCameraMatrix();
DrawSomeStuff();

glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
glViewport(0, 0, window.width, window.height);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
SetUpPerspectiveAndCameraMatrix();
obj.Draw();
SwapBuffers();
```

`glxinfo` excerpt:

```
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.4, 128 bits)
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 10.1.3
```

The problem is that the call to `glClearBufferfv` doesn't seem to clear the whole buffer. As you can see, it clears the triangular shape, but it doesn't touch the other areas. They are also not the `glClearColor` color (pink). If I use the regular `glClear` call, it does the same thing, but pink instead of cyan.

[image: Clear problem]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I created a feedback loop by drawing the fullscreen quad while the FBO was bound, drawing the contents of the buffer to itself. Apparently the effects of this end up being interspersed with the effects of `glClear`.